# how do I insert a string datetime into mysql using c++

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime, utc

I have a datetime field in the following format:

```
string date = "Jun 23 19:47:15 +0000 2010";
```

how do I insert it ito datetime field in mysql table? I am assuming I have to convert the date into unix timestamp before I insert it into the table.

Comment: Actually, you may have to convert the date into the MySQL format.  You could also just store the date as a string.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it just stores the date to default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. my pub_date field is datetime. It seems I have to convert the string date into mysql format. How do I do this in c++? Also, is there a class that will format the date from EST to GMT/UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've got an sql-injection attack waiting to happen. Had to be said.

Ok, that huge problem swept aside, you can either convert the date to a MySQL format (such as a UTC timestamp then converted again with FROM_UNIXTIME()), or tell MySQL how to convert it using STR_TO_DATE(). Both are documented in the MySQL manual, under the section "Date and Time Functions".

Answer (score 0):

You create an SQL statement to do so and then call an SQL API to tell the SQL server to execute your statement.

Comment: I will rephrase my question. I have a string datetime as captioned above and I have a mysql table called records. I want to insert this datetime into records. For arguendo, records has two fields int(id) and datetime(pub_date). Now, data insertion is normally done using sql statement, e.g.:  
<pre><code> string sql = "insert into records (id,pub_date) values ("+id+",'"+datetime+"'"; 
</pre></code> 
Now the problem is datetime is not in correct format. I am assuming the string datetime has to be converted into unix timestamp before I insert the date into my table. If so, how do I do this?